# C# Program working with PHP server

Tags: c#, php

Just curious about the best way to go about this. I want to make a webpage that shows the amount of time it takes to ping all the machines on my network. I want a C# program to do the pinging and report it to the webpage. I want to be able to click "Re-ping" on the webpage and the program rerun the test. What is the best way to go about this?

The biggest issue is how to get things from the user to the C# program.

I can make the program post on the server, and the server show the user, like below.

```
User <----> PHP Host <---- C# Program
```

However how could I get data to go the other way?

```
PHP Host ---?-->C# Program
```

Am I thinking about this all wrong?

I do want the pinging and other things to be handled by a C# program as it has far more complex functionality (threading, connections, etc) than a PHP host that is interpreted as it is requested.

Is it possible that I could let the C# program return pages to users and avoid a PHP server all-togeather?

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, including the tags `web` and `server` does not mean you are talking about web servers.  They stand alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options. If you want to avoid using a PHP server the simplest would probably be to write a simple http server similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C). Other options include using ASP.NET with a C# backend, or a webservice, which would be accessed from the PHP script or directly by a client application.

Comment: Do you recommend either of the options more than the others? I want this to monitor my network, have a web interface, allow executing things from the web interface, and for it to be secure. Oh, and thanks for the response :)

Comment: It really depends what you have available and what you are familiar with. If it's PHP than go with PHP, and the PHP script should call the C# function, probably using COM. If you are familiar with ASP.NET then that would be the best route.